# wxWidgets, is Bind fairly new? because my compiler says it isn't defined. wxVer 2.8.12.1, I've been using Bind in wxPython for.... well 2.6 at least

Tags: c++, c++11, wxpython, wxwidgets

I get an error when trying to use Bind, GCC doesn't believe it to be declared (and I believe that) I want to use Bind like I do with wxPython, the switch so far has been very easy (I don't care much for event tables).

Anyway, Bind is in the documentation but I'm guessing for a later version.

My question to you guys is:

Is "Bind" fairly new? Why has wxPython had it for a lot longer?

Or have I missed a config flag (I don't believe I have)

I'm sorry this question is quite poor, there's no need for code because it's not a code problem (I spelled "Bind" right and so forth) I'm just, should I look at using Connect? Or build a new wxWidgets.

ADDENDUM:
I'd like to know why wxPython has had it for longer, was Bind planned and it's just really easy to implement in Python?

Comment: I guess python as a language is more flexible than C++, for example it's not strongly typed. So it's easier to implement something fairly complicated as binding, whereas in C++ it's not that easy. That would explain why it came later.

Comment: afaik `Bind()` in wxWidgets and wxPython are not related. There is older wxWidgets function `Connect()` for the same purpose. When a simpler syntax for connecting events was proposed, it was necessary to use different name; `Bind` was a good choice (short verb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the documentation:

> Bind() Issues
>
> wxWidgets 2.9.0 introduced a new Dynamic Event Handling system, using wxEvtHandler::Bind<>() and Unbind<>(). This functionality uses templates behind the scenes and therefore is vulnerable to breakage in shared library builds, as described above.
>
> Currently only Unbind<>() needs the type information, so you should be immune to this problem simply if you only need to use Bind<>() and not Unbind<>().
>
> Also, if you only bind and unbind same event handler inside same binary, you should be fine.

It was in the tab just before my question, source:
http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_cpp_rtti_disabled.html#overview_cpp_rtti_disabled_bind

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately http://docs.wxwidgets.org/ is down right now so I can't provide a direct link, but if you look at [`Bind()` documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/search.php?query=Bind) you should see "Since wxWidgets 2.9.0" in it: all methods added since about 2.8.0 have these `@since` tags to indicate the minimal version they are available in.